# How to stop a "ArrayIndexOutOfBounds" exception

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

Hi guys I've been learning java over the summer and this is the last assignment, and I'm stuck. The program is supposed to take 13 numbers that I enter, sort them and then find the index number of the greatest number that I input in the original array. I'm trying to see if my selection method works but every time I try to enter in the numbers I get an out of bounds error. This is kind of frustrating and I've been trying to find and answer for a couple of hours now. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class fmax
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int indmax;
    int[] fmax = new int[13];
    fillmax(fmax);
    //System.out.println(fmax);
    indmax = maxfmax(fmax);
    //indmin = minfmax();
    System.out.println(indmax);
  }

  public static void fillmax(int[] farray)
  {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < farray.length; i++)
    {
      farray[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
   }

    public static int maxfmax(int[] farray)
    {
      int[] copy = farray;
      int j, x=0, i;
      boolean flag = true;
      int temp;

      while(flag)
      {
        flag = false;
        for( j = 0; j < copy.length -1; j++)
        {
          if(copy[j] < copy[j+1])
          {
            temp = copy[j];
            copy[j] = copy[j+1];
            copy[j+1] = temp;
            flag = true;
          }
         }

        for(i=0; i <= farray.length; i++)
        {
         if(farray[i] == copy[1])
           x = i;
        }
      }
       return x;
    }
 }
```

Comment: in `for(i=0; i <= farray.length; i++)`

Answer (score 5):

This line will throw the out of bounds exception.

```
for(i=0; i <= farray.length; i++)
```

Your termination condition is incorrect.  Try this:

```
for(i=0; i < farray.length; i++)
```

so that you stop the loop before you go past the last index (`farray.length - 1`).

Comment: Ah! I can't believe I forgot that one! Thanks very much that error was beginning to ruin my day

Answer (score 0):

You defined the Lenght of the Array as 13 than you run this line:

```
for(i=0; i <= farray.length; i++)
```

This means you will go for the items `fmax[13]` which doesnt exist, because java starts counting at 0. So the hightest index is `fmax[12]`. You need to change your condition to something like that:

```
for(i=0; i < farray.length; i++)
```

or

```
for(i=0; i <= farray.length -1; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case `length` for `array` is returning size of your array - but it starts with 1 not with zero.

```
i <= farray.length   - causes out of bounds exception
```

u have to use - as was mentioned `i < farray.length` in your for loop

Answer (score 0):

Array always has index beginning with zero and ending with length-1

```
for(i=0; i <= farray.length; i++)
```

Your terminating condition is wrong. It is trying to access element located at index length, which does not exist and hence you get the exception. It should be modified to something like below to make it work:

```
for(i=0; i < farray.length; i++)
```